# TikZ not detecting third intersection of curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, tikz-path

I want to find the intersections of a graph in a certain *y*-value in order to create a hybrid path between the curves. However, for some reason, TikZ is not detecting the third intersection.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
             xlabel style={below right}, ylabel style={above left}, ticks=none,
             xmin=0, xmax=3.5, ymin=0, ymax=1]

\addplot[name path=Tb, domain={0.4:3.4},samples=500] {-3/x^2+(8*0.85)/(3*x-1)};

\draw[name path=l1] (axis cs:0.5, 0.57) -- (axis cs:3.35,0.57);
\draw[red, name path=part1, intersection segments={of=Tb and l1, sequence={L1--R2--L3}}];

\fill [name intersections={of=l1 and Tb, name=E, total=\t}]
[red] 
\foreach \s in {1,2,...,\t}{(E-\s) circle (1pt)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image]

As we clearly see, there is a third intersection between the curves but TikZ cannot detect it. Even when I separate the horizontal line in two portions, TikZ does not detect that last point. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! I can't reproduce your problem! Which version of the `pgfplots` package you use? It is good praxis after loading `pgfplots` add  to add  `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}` (i.e. that is employed recent last version of it).

Comment: That's odd. I guess I'm using version 1.15 since adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}` gives the following error `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, 'compat=1.17' is unknown in this context. Please use at most 'compat=1.15'`. Perhaps that is the problem. How do you update the package?

Answer (score 2):

- I encourage you to upgrade your ˙pgfplots` installation (it is not crucial to find third intersection, but anyway, it is worth to do so)
- I guessing, that you like to obtain the following graph:

[image]

In comparison to your MWE I only add fourth segment in drawing red lines and use recent syntax enabled with `pgfplots` after version 1.11:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween,
                intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle, 
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={below right}, 
    ylabel style={above left}, 
    ticks=none,
    xmin=0, xmax=3.5, ymin=0, ymax=1
                ]

\addplot[name path=Tb, domain={0.4:3.4},samples=101] {-3/x^2+(8*0.85)/(3*x-1)};

\draw[name path=l1] (0.5, 0.57) -- (3.35,0.57);
\draw[red, intersection segments={of=Tb and l1, sequence={L1--R2--L3--R4}}]; % <---

\fill [name intersections={of=l1 and Tb, name=E, total=\t}] 
      [red, very thick, semitransparent]
    \foreach \s in {1,2,...,\t}{(E-\s) circle[radius=2pt] };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solution should also works with `pgfplots` version 1.15 (not tested).

Comment: Well, I tried your code only changing `pgfplots` to version 1.15 and the following error appeared: `Package pgf Error: There is no intersection segment '3' in path '2'.`

Comment: I tested with v1.14 on overleaf with 101 samples and it works! However, with 201 samples not. However, Overleaf doesn't use recent version of LaTeX as well of packages, so it’s no surprise, that it doesn't work as one can expected. So I suggest you (i) reduce number of sample to 101 (as I already corrected in my answer) (ii) anyway upgrade your complete LaTeX installation.  BTW, I use recent MiKTeX.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking... (with the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzpolot) package:)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tzplot}   %%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2]
\tzhelplines[step=.5](3.5,1)
\tzaxes*(3.5,1){$x$}{$y$}
\def\Tb{-3/(\x)^2+(8*0.85)/(3*\x-1)}
\begin{scope}
  \clip(0,0)rectangle(3.5,1);
  \tzfn\Tb[0.4:3.4]
  \tzhfnat[red]"hori"{0.57}[0.4:3.4]
  \tzXpoint{Tb}{hori}(A)
\end{scope}
\tzdots*(A)(A-2)(A-3);   %% (A)=(A-1)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```